# How to chop up looping in PHP

Tags: php

i have a large csv to loop through and make an arrays.
But i wanna loop several times and begin on next line.

Example:

```
function getCsv($housesCsv) {
    $file=fopen("example.csv", "r");
    while(! feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $housesCsv[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
    array_shift($housesCsv);
    return $housesCsv;
};

print_r($housesCsv) =
Array ( [0] => 01.110,HE [1] => 01.120,HE [2] => 01.130,HE [3] => 01.141,HE [4] => 01.142,HE [5] => 01.150,HE [6] => 01.161,HE [7] => 01.162,HE [8] => 01.173,HE [9] => 01.174,HE [10] => 01.183,HE [11] => 01.400,HE [12] => 01.500,HE [13] => 01000,BB [14] => 01100,BB [15] => 01101,BB [16] => 011012,BB [17] => 01102,BB [18] => 011022,BB [19] => 01110,BB [20] => 01111,BB [21] => 01112,BB [22] => 011131,BB [23] => 011141,BB [24] => 01120,BB [25] => 01121,BB [26] => 01122,BB [27] => 01123,BB [28] => 01124,BB [29] => 01141,BB [30] => 01142,BB )

function writeTxt() {
$housesCsv = [];
$order = 1;
$loopLength = 30;
$concat = ", ";
$houses = getCsv($housesCsv);

foreach($houses as $house) {

        if($order <= $loopLength) { 
        if(!empty($house)) {
        $line = rtrim($house) . $concat . $order++;
        $txt[] = strval($line);
        }; //if
        $text2 = implode($concat, $txt);
   (after making more then one loops i have $text3)     
print_r($text3) =
Array ( [0] => 01.110,HE, 1, 01.120,HE, 2, 01.130,HE, 3, 01.141,HE, 4, 01.142,HE, 5, 01.150,HE, 6, 01.161,HE, 7, 01.162,HE, 8, 01.173,HE, 9, 01.174,HE, 10, 01.183,HE, 11, 01.400,HE, 12, 01.500,HE, 13, 01000,BB, 14, 01100,BB, 15, 01101,BB, 16, 011012,BB, 17, 01102,BB, 18, 011022,BB, 19, 01110,BB, 20, 01111,BB, 21, 01112,BB, 22, 011131,BB, 23, 011141,BB, 24, 01120,BB, 25, 01121,BB, 26, 01122,BB, 27, 01123,BB, 28, 01124,BB, 29, 01141,BB, 30;
[1] => ... , 60)
        
        }; 
        };

};

writeTxt();
```

So i wanna have 100 loops like that and the $order is where i wanna start the next loop (second loop would be from 31). How can i do that?
Please help me.

Comment: Is this intentional to have `$loopLenght = 30;` be spelled differently than `if($order <= $loopLength) {`?

Comment: The first question is 'why do you want to do this?'. Memory isn't an issue, so maybe run time is the problem. The only reliable way with `fgetcsv` to get to a specific line in a file is to read and discard all the lines before it, so every restart you're reading the whole file again. Perhaps some preprocessing with [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)) is a better idea. This looks very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: ty hppycoder, changed it.

Comment: XY Problem: It is a challenge for a job interview. I would never split it , because memory is also  no issue for my machine. Splitting beforehand...i can try that, ty.

Comment: can you show input with the expected output

Comment: @Lawrence: I have put some print_rs to show the arrays...these are shorter then my code. But i hope its ok.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php ?

Comment: @  β.εηοιτ.βε : yeah, i will try it immidiately, ty.

Comment: You helped me alot, ty. Array-chunk was the way to go for me!